# Git error: remote: Permission to username/repo.git denied to username. fatal: unable to access 'github link': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, authentication, github, push

I am getting this error message when trying to push to my git repository. I have tried to unset all users then set it again. Tried SSH and literally every single possible solution on the internet, but none of it worked for me. Anyone got this message and could help me with it? Really appriceate if you answer I hadn't been able to use github since then.

Answer (score 1):

On Github navigate to Settings/ Developer settings/ Personal access tokens

Select Fine Grained Tokens then Generate New Token.

Under Permissions, you can grant Read and Write access to "Contents" to allow git push to the repository.